# Does Primal Base commited to Omnipresence count for the sake of calculating evolution?

Tags: religions-and-deities, experience-points, the-primal-order

To clarify the scenario I have in mind is a deity using limited omnipresence on their biggest temple on a particular plane since the religious dogma they cultivated involves them always being in that temple. Would the thousand base committed to this location be included when calculating how much primal base that deity gains every year?

Relevant passages:

> Prerequisites: Lesser deity or above.

> Cost in flux: 1,000 points.

> Cost in base: 20 points.The deity must also commit 1,000 points for the duration of the effect; these points are recovered when the
> effect ends.

> Omnipresence allows deities to diffuse some or all of their essences into
> an entire area, gaining an enhanced awareness of anything taking place within
> that area. The area of effect is a sphere one mile in diameter; The deity is
> aware of anything happening within the area of effect. A deity using omnipresence may direct primal energy through any point in the area of effect, and in
> fact may instantly transport his or her physical form to anywhere in the area
> of effect at no cost, as long as the physical form starts out in the area of effect.
> The deity may also communicate individually with any Lifeform or group of
> Lifeforms in the area of effect.

> Deities, like all characters, gain mastery of their skills over time. Since primal
> base is a reflection of how well deities may impose their will upon reality,
> it stands to reason that over time, this mastery is reflected in the amount of
> primal base the deities have at hand. As a result, deities who have been around
> a long time have an inherent advantage due to experience.
> The amount of primal base that a deity has increases by I% each year
> automatically.

Comment: As a side-note, I am very happy to find someone still playing The Primal Order.

Comment: 'Playing' is not the word I would use. I am using it for the sake of simulating gods in my setting since there is no way I can get my players interested in non-D&D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Real answer: Up to the GM.

Rules-wise: No. 20 points are permanently lost (the "cost"), and 1000 points are lost as long as the effect (limited omnipresence) is active. The 20 points are noticeably twice that of the lost "interest" (1% of 1000 = 10 points) to discourage you from turning the effect on and off for the sake of the yearly increase.